# Automatically Update MS Excel Formula when Field Value is changed

Tags: excel, vba

Scenario: I have two MS excel Columns `B3:B200` and `C3:C200`, Column `C` values area Fed externally from a database however column B compares what is in column `C` and gives it an alias value, example if Column `C's` Value is: Damian, Column `B` gives the following value: Dames, I have written the formula for that:`IF($C$3:$C$200="Damian","Dames","")` which works, however my issue is if the data in the `C column` changes how can I have a function the goes in to the function: `IF($C$3:$C$200="Damian","Dames","")` and automatically change the hardcoded texts `Damian` and `Dames`

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate table that stores your hardcoded text conversions, then perform a vlookup against that.

Your new formula would look like:
If using 2010 or later...
`=IFERROR(Vlookup(C3,LookupTable($A$2:$B$500),2,false),"")`

*Note - the references in my formula are placeholders